# Angularjs - display current date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a view in angularjs and I'm just trying to display the current date(formatted). I thought something like `<span>{{Date.now() | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>` should display the current date.

Comment: It would.. but it doesn't know `Date.now()`.

Comment: So I got to generate the variable in the controller first? I thought something simple like the current date would be easier :)

Comment: `Date.now()` is nodeJS function

Comment: @Nay no it isn't https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You have to create a date object in your controller first:

controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope)
{
    $scope.date = new Date();
}
```

view:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RyW9m/)

[Angular Date Filter Ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: hi @sloth I want to use cgi for displaying the current system time. How can I possibly do that?or is it possible?Thanks

Answer (score 44):

You can also do this with a filter if you don't want to have to attach a date object to the current scope every time you want to print the date:

```
.filter('currentdate',['$filter',  function($filter) {
    return function() {
        return $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    };
}])
```

and then in your view:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div>{{'' | currentdate}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He may as well make a directive then

Answer (score 23):

**Template**

```
<span date-now="MM/dd/yyyy"></span>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('dateNow', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  return {
    link: function( $scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.text($filter('date')(new Date(), $attrs.dateNow));
    }
  };
}])
```

Because you can't access the `Date` object direcly in a template (for an inline solution), I opteted for this Directive. It also keeps your Controllers clean and is reusable.

Answer (score 20):

Well, You can do it with mustache expression (`{{Date.now() | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}`). You just need to assign the Date object to scope where You want to evaluate this expression.

Here's jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/628cf/1/)

But don't expect it to update value automatically. This value is not watched by angular so You have to trigger digest every time You want to get it updated (by $interval for example)...which is waste of resources (and also not "recommended" in docs). Of course You can get to use of combination with directives/controllers to mess around with child scope only (it's always smaller than for example rootScope and digest will be quicker).

Answer (score 9):

Just my 2 cents in case someone stumble upon this :)

What I am suggesting here will have the same result as the current answer however it has been recommended to write your controller the way that I have mentioned here.

[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) scroll to the first **"Note"** (Sorry it doesn't have anchor)

Here is the recommended way:

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);   
app.controller( 'MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
}]);
```

View:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `moment()` and `format()` functions in AngularJS.

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);   
app.controller( 'demoCtrl', ['$scope', '$moment' function($scope , $moment) {
$scope.date = $moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
}]);
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-app="demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    {{date}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('sampleapp', [])
app.controller('samplecontrol', function ($scope) {
   var today = new Date();
   console.log($scope.cdate);
   var date = today.getDate();
   var month = today.getMonth();
   var year = today.getFullYear();
   var current_date = date+'/'+month+'/'+year;
   console.log(current_date);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample of your answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/MKugkgCSpdZFefSeDRi7?p=preview

```
<span>Date Of Birth: {{DateOfBirth | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}}</span>
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
```

and then in the controller:

```
$scope.DateOfBirth = new Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

**View**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
{{AssignedDate.now() | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
</div>
```

**Controller**

var app = angular.module('myapp',[])

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.AssignedDate = Date;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to [the one of @Nick G.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25594925/2045384) by using filter, but make the parameter meaningful:

Implement an filter called `relativedate` which calculate the date relative to current date by the given parameter as diff. As a result, `(0 | relativedate)` means today and `(1 | relativedate)` means tomorrow.

```
.filter('relativedate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return function (rel, format) {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + rel);
    return $filter('date')(date, format || 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  };
}]);
```

and your html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div>Yesterday: {{-1 | relativedate}}</div>
    <div>Today: {{0 | relativedate}}</div>
    <div>Tomorrow: {{1 | relativedate}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing is:
In Controller, create a variable to hold the current date as shown below:

```
var eventsApp = angular.module("eventsApp", []);
eventsApp.controller("EventController", function EventController($scope) 
{

 $scope.myDate = Date.now();

});
```

In HTML view,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="eventsApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title></title>
   <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="EventController">
<span>{{myDate | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Billa, I have updated my code snippet. I hope, it is more descriptive now.