# Angular js Current date display issue

Tags: angularjs, ng-bootstrap

I'm a beginner in **Angularjs** and `ng-bootstrap`. I've created a sample Web site and added navigation for my site. It's working good, but I have some issue, I'm trying to display current date as **`2017-12-18`** this one is not displayed, I want to know how to added correctly to my site
I'm following this [Angularjs - display current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962468/angularjs-display-current-date)

**app-navbar.component.html**

```
       <div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
          {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}<br/>
        </div>

    <script>
  function Ctrl($scope)
   {
    $scope.date = new Date();
     }
    </script>
```

**app-navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-navbar',
      templateUrl: './app-navbar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app-navbar.component.css']
    })
    export class AppNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Comment: are you sure what you want to do? you just cannot add script tags in html in Angular.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding between **Angular** and **AngularJS**. Can you clarify which one you want to use? Judging by the use of TypeScript you probably want to use Angular 2/4/5. But the examples you are looking at are for AngularJS (1 - 1.6)

Comment: Sir , how t o added `app-navbar` to `controller`, Its should be fix, I Need to add controller, but i don't know wheres to added this controller

Comment: @core114 it's best for you to stick with JavaScript and avoid ES6 syntax for now

Comment: Sir thanks for the guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-navbar',
      templateUrl: './app-navbar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app-navbar.component.css']
    })
    export class AppNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
      public date = new Date();
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

try this. For format refer: https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-tips-formatting-dates-with-a-custom-date-pipe-dd-mm-yyyy/

Comment: welcome @core114, Happy Coding. Could you please accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove script tags from your template, and update your component like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './app-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-navbar.component.css']
})
export class AppNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public date = new Date()
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you mixed angularjs by angular2 
your **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './app-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-navbar.component.css']
})
export class AppNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  date = new Date();
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

your **app-navbar.component.html**

```
 <div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
          {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}<br/>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sir,all of solutions are work for me, Im vote up all of you