# How to get a year, month and day in angular?

Tags: angular, date

I tried this code to get year, month and day in Angular but it doesn't work.

```
d = new Date();
```

It gives me the full date with time.
How can I customize this code to give me only year , month and the day?
thanks <3

Comment: Is it for Angular or angular2?

Comment: What the exact format you want ? Are you expecting yyyy/MM/dd ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs - display current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962468/angularjs-display-current-date)

Comment: You can use [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) library for easy parsing of date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format according to your need :

```
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear()
    var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
      "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
      "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");  

    var today = curr_date + "-" + months[curr_month] + "-" + curr_year
```